# Trickle charging with positive and negative on the same battery terminal

Tags: electrical, battery, charger

I have a trickle charger cable on my motorcycle battery and in the dark I mistakenly put both charger cable leads on the positive battery terminal, what happened to the battery by trickle charging with both positive and negative on the same battery terminal?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happened to the battery.

If your trickle charger doesn't have short circuit protection, it may be destroyed now. However, the battery is unaffected.

Try to test if your charger works by charging with it normally, by putting positive to positive and negative to negative.